# How do I import a whitespace-delimited text file into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, mysqlimport

I need to import largish (24MB) text files into a MySQL table. Each line looks like this:

```
1 1 0.008  0  0  0  0  0
```

There are one or more spaces after each field, and the last field is tailed by about 36 spaces before the newline.

How do I import such a file into MySQL? From the documentation it seems that LOAD DATA expects all fields to be terminated by exactly the same string. I have tried

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ';
```

but MySQL will interpret a sequence of more than one space as delimiting an empty field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're on unix/linux then you can put it through sed.

open a terminal and type:

```
sed 's/ \+/ /g' thefile > thefile.new
```

this replaces all sequences of multiple spaces with one space.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, just use Excel.

Excel will import a whitespace-delimited file (check the 'treat subsequent delimiters as one' box from the import menu).

Then you can simply save the file as a CSV from Excel and import into MySQL using:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the same command posted by Jauco to change the delimiter to ';' or \n.
That would also help.

Comment: Not really; MySQL is quite happy with spaces as field delimiters, it's only the multiple ones that are a problem here. And using LFs would make it worse as they'd then be the same as the record delimiters!

Answer (score 0):

Is there no way you can do this pragmatically? A simple PHP script would be able to load the file in, split by spaces, and do an insert in no time at all:

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password')
or die('Failed to connect');
mysql_select_db('database', $db);

$fileHandle= @fopen("import.file", "r");
if ($fileHandle) {
    while (!feof($fileHandle)) {
        $rawLine = fgets($fileHandle, 4096);

        $columns = preg_split("/\s+/", $rawLine);

        //Construct and run an INSERT statement here ...   

    }
    fclose($fileHandle);
}

?>
```

**Edit**
That being said, [Jakal's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156532/how-do-i-import-a-whitespace-delimited-text-file-into-mysql#156550) suggestion is far neater ;)