# Loading fixed-width, space delimited .txt file into mySQL

Tags: mysql, file-io, load, local

I have a .txt file that has a bunch of formatted data in it that looks like the following:

```
...
   1     75175.18     95128.46
   1    790890.89    795829.16
   1    875975.98    880914.25
   8   2137704.37   2162195.53
   8   2167267.27   2375275.28
  10   2375408.74   2763997.33
  14   2764264.26   2804437.77
  15   2804504.50   2881981.98
  16   2882048.72   2887921.25
  16   2993093.09   2998031.36
  19   3004104.10   3008041.37
...
```

I am trying to load each row as an entry into a table in my database, where each column is a different field.  I am having trouble getting mySQL to separate all of the data properly.  I think the issue is coming from the fact that not all of the numbers are separated with an equidistant white-space amount.

Here are two queries I have tried so far (I have also tried several variations of these queries):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'/some/Path/segmentation.txt' 
INTO TABLE clip (slideNum, startTime, endTime) 
SET presID = 1;


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'/some/Path/segmentation.txt' 
INTO TABLE clip 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(slideNum, startTime, endTime) 
SET presID = 1;
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: Also, notice the single white space at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are what we call "fixed-width" records and LOAD DATA doesn't play well with them. Options:

1. Clean up data in Excel first, or
2. Load up the data to a temp table with only 1 column, shoving an entire text row into that column. Then you can use `SUBSTR()` and `TRIM()` to slice out the columns you need into the final table.
3. Or with user variables (@row) you can do it all within the LOAD DATA statement.

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'/some/Path/segmentation.txt' 
INTO TABLE clip
(@row)
SET slideNum = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,1,4)),
    startTime = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,5,13)),
    endTime = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,18,13))
;
```

Comment: Ok, cool.  Would this query work better if there was only one space in-between every value?  It would probably not be that difficult to write a script that made the spacing more consistent.

Comment: Typically you should use commas, semicolons, tabs, or pipes ('|') to separate fields in text files (CSV = comma-separated values is most common format). Then LOAD DATA can handle them easily.

Comment: Wow, option 3 (and the query that went along with it) worked perfectly , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
INFILE 'DCF Master 14APR2013 VSPCFM_reduced size.txt'
INTO TABLE EMPLOYEE3
(
a = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,1,11)),
b = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,33,38)),
c = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,70,86))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're on unix/linux then you can put it through sed to strip out spaces. The  [solution is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/156550/13068500)
2. You can programmatically replace spaces with a different delimiter. I decided to use **PHP**, you can also safely do it in **Python**

   ```
   <?php
   $mysqli  =  new mysqli(
   "***",
   "***",
   "***",
   "***",
   3306
   );
   mysqli_options($mysqli, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);

   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
       exit();
   }

   function createTempFileWithDelimiter($filename, $path){
       $content = file_get_contents($filename);
       $replaceContent = preg_replace('/\ +/', ',', $content); // NOT \s+

       $onlyFileName = explode('\\',$filename);

       $newFileName = $path.end($onlyFileName);
       file_put_contents($newFileName, $replaceContent);

       return $newFileName;
   }

   $pathTemp = 'C:\\TempDir\\';

   $pathToFile = 'C:\\some\\Path\\segmentation.txt';

   $file = createFileWithDelimiter($pathToFile, $pathTemp);
   $file = str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', $file);

   $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file."' INTO TABLE `clip` 
       COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  // or '\r\n'
       (slideNum, startTime, endTime)
       SET presID = 1;";

   if (!($stmt = $mysqli->query($sql))) {
       echo "\nQuery execute failed: ERRNO: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
   };

   unlink($file);
   ?>
   ```

Don't use '/\s+/' in **preg_replace** because \s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ]) and the formatting will change, columns and line breaks will disappear.