# Timeout importing huge txt in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, timeout

I'm trying to import a huge txt in mysql.
it is my first attempt to use php and mysql so I'm not sure where is the problem.
I have a txt of almost the 4 million row and I need to store it in a db.
I wrote this pice of php to do the job:

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'commuting');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$handle = fopen("matrix_pendo2001.txt", "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {

        $line = fgets($handle, 4096);

        $a = substr($line,0,3);
        $b = substr($line,4,3);
        $c = substr($line,8,1);
        $d = substr($line,10,1);
        $e = substr($line,12,1);
        $f = substr($line,14,3);
        $g = substr($line,18,3);
        $h = substr($line,22,3);
        $i = substr($line,26,1);
        $l = substr($line,28,2);
        $m = substr($line,31,1);
        $n = substr($line,33,1);
        $o = substr($line,35,8);

        $sql="INSERT INTO ita (ProvRes, ComRes, Sesso, Motivo, Luogo, ProvLav, ComLav, StatExt, MercPrev, Mezzo, Ora, Tempo, Num)
        VALUES 
        ('$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e', '$f', '$g', '$h', '$i', '$l', '$m', '$n', '$o')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
          }
        echo "record '<b>" . $line . "'</b> added. <br/>";

    }
    fclose($handle);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

The script seems to work well, but I can't get all the row in the db.
after less than 1 million the script ends without apparent error.
I have set the max_execution_time to 0 and increased the memory_limit to 2048MB but nothing change.

Comment: do you run it through command line?

Comment: Don't do it this way. In fact, don't use PHP at all. Look at `LOAD DATA INFILE` in the [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html). It'll do the job faster and more reliably.

Comment: I'm not running the code in the terminal, I just load the php page in the browser. I'm now trying to use LOAD DATA INFILE (look at the mcuadors answer) but stil not working right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use LOAD DATA INFILE, this SQL command can be executed directly in the server and will avoid timeouts and will be the fastest way because run in localhost.

This is a small example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES STARTING BY 'xxx';
```

Based on this question: [loading-fixed-width-space-delimited-txt-file-into-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461790/loading-fixed-width-space-delimited-txt-file-into-mysql) you can try this possible solution:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'/yourfile.txt' 
INTO TABLE clip
(@row)
SET a = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,0,3)),
    b = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,4,3)),
    c = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,10,1)),
    ......
;
```

Comment: the problem is the file is a txt with no delimiter, but with fix column: first start a 0 char; second at 4, third at 8 etc (see the substring varible). An ex row look like this: "001 001 1 1 1 001 001     1 06 1 1        2"

Comment: I see, then first fix the CSV and after use LOAD DATA, will be many many times more faster. I promise is the better way.

Comment: How can I convert my txt in a working CSV? and How to use Load Data?

Comment: No... there something wrong... The query is super fast but it generates 1192 record and the data stored are not the one in the txt... it seems like some encoding problem. here a screenshoot https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhn3fzoqmw0r52a/Screenshot%202013-11-26%2000.27.26.png

Comment: I delete the file and make a new copy of it and now the query works!!! only 68.5925 sec to import 3870728 row. The only error in the query is the SUBSTR because the count start at 1 and not at 0.